# can we track downloading of attachment from gmail?

Tags: android, networking, gmail

suppose i am on wifi network and i m downloading some attachment from my mobile phone.So is it possible that the copy of download is saved on any server machine between my phone and gmail sever.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail client uses HTTPS (SSL) and even the web client defaults to HTTPS. If you set the web client to use HTTP, someone could intercept you traffic and extract the attachment. But in the standard HTTPS configuration, they couldn't do this even if you were using an unprotected WiFi hotspot, etc.

Comment: But then again, this is not a programming question, is it?